# Typeerror float is not callable. Im trying to figure out why my elif statement are not callable

Tags: python, function, typeerror

```
from cisc106_32 import*

def BillAmount(mb):


    if mb <= 50:
        price=50

    elif 50<mb<=400:
        price=(66.50+(.05)(mb-50.00))

    elif 400<mb<=1000:
        price=(72.00+(.08)(mb-50.00))

    else:
        price=100.00

    return price

assertEqual(BillAmount(45),50)

assertEqual(BillAmount(400),84)

assertEqual(BillAmount(2000),100)
```

Comment: Why do you expect Python to multiply without a `*`?

Answer (score 2):

In most programming languages, when multiplying numbers, you need a `*`.  e.g.:

```
result = (0.5) * (mb - 50.00)
```

(unlike in math when you write `result=(0.5)(y)(500)` and the multiplication is implied.)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to make a float number into a function:

```
(.05)(mb-50.00)
```

If you meant to multiply the two values, use `*`:

```
(.05) * (mb-50.00)
```

Illustration:

```
>>> mb=51
>>> (.05)(mb-50.00)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
>>> (.05)*(mb-50.00)
0.050000000000000003
```

Answer (score 1):

In Python, `()` is regarded as `function operator`.. So, if you add parenthesis to any word in Python, it becomes a function call (Well, there are some exceptions though, but that is not the concern here) ..

So, if you do this:  -`(2)(5)` , you are not multiplying 2 and 5, rather you are trying to invoke a function `2` which does not exists with argument `5`..

So, add a `*` in between these parenthesis to make it `(2)*(5)`

Comment: +1 for explaining what the actual problem is, and why the OP got the specific error he did.